# Cron ignoring an update to crontab

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab

I've commented out a line in the crontab on a debian server, which I guess was there by default yet was causing me to get error emails every hour:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *   * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

However, the error emails keep coming in as if it hasn't been commented out. The error emails:

```
Subject: Cron <root@(none)> root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly (failed)
/bin/sh: root: not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't be easier to `sudo vi crontab`, that way you are modifying root's crontab?

Comment: @patrick: I'm logging in as root, so there's no sudo..

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else, I received this error because I ran `crontab -e /etc/crontab`, which DOES NOT safely edit /etc/crontab. It creates a duplicate that generates this error, and can be removed by running `crontab -r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "the crontab" you're not being specific. You should say which one you mean. However, based on the contents, it looks like `/etc/crontab`. Since that file does have a user field, it doesn't make sense that you'd get that error. My bet is that there's a user crontab that has that line in it. User crontabs don't contain user fields.

The proper thing to do is not to change that line in `/etc/crontab`. There may be other jobs it runs.

You can edit that file and the files in the `/etc/cron.*` subdirectories using any editor. You can specify the editor you want to use when you use `crontab -e` by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable.

You should use `crontab -e` to edit user crontabs (including root's). Remove the user field or remove that line in the *user* crontab where it appears (not `/etc/crontab`). User crontabs don't have a user field, but the system crontabs do.

User crontabs are located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. You can `sudo grep` for the line to find out which file has the stray line. Again, only use `crontab -u username -e` to edit the user crontab.

Answer (score 2):

Check the manpage on your system for crontab(5) (`man 5 crontab`), especially under the "EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE" section.  Only the /etc/crontab file includes a username field.  Non-system user crontabs do not include this field.  If you want to edit /etc/crontab, then use a text editor, not the crontab(1) command.